# How to run two radeon video cards (one old, one new) after catalyst dropped unified driver?

Tags: multiple-monitors, amd-radeon, amd-catalyst, display-driver

(Apologies for the rather long post...)

On early 2012, i was running a Radeon HD2400 and a HD6950 on the same computer, driving 3 monitors; primary monitor on the HD6950 and two side monitors on the HD2400. Everything works just fine.

Now some time later, one of the monitors broke down so i only had two left. Because of this, I removed the HD2400 and ran both monitors directly on the HD6950.

I recently got an extra monitor available and thought i'd just install the old HD2400 back in. I was surprised to learn that this is not the case anymore because AMD removed support for older cards (HD2000/3000/4000) since catalyst 12.7 or something.

> Source http://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=article&item=amd_catalyst_legacy2&num=1

So here's the question: is there any way i can make this work on my setup? (Windows 7 x64, 16GB RAM, i2500K, intel z68, radeon HD6950)

Some additional info:

- List item I have tried downloading and installing the "legacy
  drivers" for    HD2000/3000/4000 and they refused to install over the
  current catalyst 13.1 driver. I can see the card in device manager, with yellow warning icon saying "the device cannot start". The card is confirmed working on another computer though, so this is 100% a driver issue.
- I do have an integrated intel vga (i believe it's HD3000 sandy bridge) but i was having stability issues (random BSOD, etc) when using it on this particular motherboard.
- the HD6950 cannot support triple monitors without one of them using an Active DisplayPort cable. This thing costs at least $50 where i live, so it's not an attractive option. None of my current monitors have DP connection, so i have to add another converter to the cost.
- Assuming there's no way i can make the old radeon cards work, would a cheap low end
  nvidia card do the job?  I've never tried running a mixed nvidia/ati card before. My understanding is that this is not a healthy thing to do, but i might be wrong...

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why don't you just use the old drivers, remove the current drivers, and replace them with the old.  You run older drivers but the HD2400 was discontinued and stop being supported longer then 12 months ago.

Comment: Thanks for the response. That would be one alternative, yes, but the driver situation around that time was awful. I'm not even sure which version is the "last" unified driver version. (Been reading the release notes just now: 12.6 is HD5000+ only, 12.5 didn't exist apparently, 12.4 is my best bet, since 12.1/2/3 were a bit problematic based on my experience).